# How do Craigslist and others insert <br> when users hit the return key in their posts?

Tags: line-breaks, craigslist

When I post something to Craigslist or to select other websites, I hit the return key twice to start a new paragraph.  I don't need to manually insert line-break elements.  Craigslist has code which recognizes the double tap of the carriage Return key as the start of a new paragraph and inserts the break elements for me.
  How do they do that?  Would like to create a website which allows non-technical users to submit multi-paragraph entries without using a stitch of html.  Have not succeeded in finding anything online.  Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine they'd use something like  `nl2br()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php